# Not able to get how reference are work in python

Tags: python, reference, binary-tree

```
a = binaryTree()
a.insert(3)
a.insert(2)
currentNode = a.root
a.inOrderTraversal()
currentNode = currentNode.left
currentNode.data = 9
# currentNode = None
# currentNode.left = None
a.inOrderTraversal()
```

You can see in above code when I put `currentNode.data = 9` and check the `inOrderTraversal` of the tree it was showing the result 9, 3 which was working as expected but when I comment out `currentNode.data = 9` and assign `currentData = None` then it will show 2, 3 which was assign earlier. Why did currentNode not become None ?

Full code:

```
class node:
  def __init__(this,data=None):
    this.left = None
    this.right = None
    this.data = data

class binaryTree:
  def __init__(this):
    this.root = None

  def insert(this,data):
    newNode = node(data)
    if(this.root == None):
      this.root = newNode
    else:
      currentNode = this.root
      while(True):
        if(data > currentNode.data):
          if(currentNode.right == None):
            currentNode.right = newNode
            break
          else:
            currentNode = currentNode.right
        else:
          if(currentNode.left == None):
            currentNode.left = newNode
            break
          else:
            currentNode = currentNode.left

  def inOrderTraversal(this):
    currentNode = this.root
    if(currentNode == None):
      return "Tree is empty"
    stack = []
    stack.append(currentNode)
    currentNode = currentNode.left
    while(True):
      if(currentNode == None and (len(stack) < 1)):
        break
      elif(currentNode == None and (len(stack) > 0)):
        node = stack.pop()
        print(node.data)
        currentNode = node.right
      else:
        stack.append(currentNode)
        currentNode = currentNode.left

a = binaryTree()
a.insert(3)
a.insert(2)
currentNode = a.root
# a.inOrderTraversal()
currentNode = currentNode.left
# currentNode.data = 9
currentNode = None
# currentNode.left = None
a.inOrderTraversal()
# print("check")
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Initially you insert 2 and 3 so that's what you get out at the end as well. With the extra line, you change the value of one of the nodes from 2 to 9 so now you get 9 and 3 (instead of 2 and 3) at the end. What did you expect instead? Why would it become None? You never set it to None, you set it to 2 (in the insert line).

Comment: @CherryDT you are write but I am saying if I comment out the `currentNode.data = 9` this line and unComment  `currentNode = None` this then why its still showing 2 I re-assign it with None

Comment: Because you are assigning currentNode to None and not currentNode.data... So you are just changing the value of your variable currentNode from a reference to a node to None, just like how currentNode = currentNode.left above changes the value from a reference to a.root to a reference to a.root.left. It's still showing 2 because nowhere in your code you modify any node anymore then (and vice versa, the traversal code doesn't access your local currentNode variable, it reads only from a.root and descendents, which never change this way)